# Change array style in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

i've been trying to make this array

```
$data = array (
    'country' => '+57',
    'message' => 'test',
    'messageFormat' => 0,
    'addresseeList' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'mobile' => '1111',
        'correlationLabel' => 'corelation ejemplo',
      ),
    )
    );
```

into this

```
$data = array();

      $data['country'] = '+57';
      $data['message'] = 'test';
      $data['messageFormat'] = 0;
      $data['addresseeList'] = array(
        
          $data['mobile'] = '1111',
          $data['correlationLabel'] = 'corelation ejemplo'
      
      );
```

But when i try to convert  this array into a json object i'm getting this

```
string(154) "{"country":"+57","message":"test","messageFormat":0,"mobile":"1111","correlationLabel":"corelation ejemplo","addresseeList":["1111","corelation ejemplo"]}"
```

but i should get something like this

```
string(128) "{"country":"+57","message":"test","messageFormat":0,"addresseeList":[{"mobile":"1111","correlationLabel":"corelation ejemplo"}]}"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The way you are inserting the address info actually places the `mobile` and `correlationLabel` at the root of the `$data` array.

instead, you need to add create an entirely new array to place as the only element inside an array you create at `$data['addresseeList']`.

```php
$data = array();

$data['country'] = '+57';
$data['message'] = 'test';
$data['messageFormat'] = 0;
$data['addresseeList'][] = array(
    'mobile' => '1111',
    'correlationLabel' => 'corelation ejemplo'
);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).PHP_EOL;
```